# Flags in Memgraph for more verbose output

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

I'm trying to load 10.9M nodes in Memgraph (no edges yet). I have a CSV file with 3 columns: ***ID, label*** and ***description***

But when loading with:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "/import-data/nodes.csv" NO HEADER AS row 
CREATE (n:BIKG_node {id: row[0], label: row[1], description: row[2]}) ;
```

the server just crashes (DockerDesktop, 10GB max). Is there any flag I can give Memgraph to get some more verbose output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the log files. Because you are running Memgraph through Docker, you will need to either enter the container using the docker exec command, for example:

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash
```

or by using volumes.